# one click demo importer ini_set and ajax warning

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I just bought a theme on wordpress and trying to import the demo with one click demo importer but I get these warnings:

> Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/ditt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/one-click-demo-import/inc/OneClickDemoImport.php on line 207
>
> Warning: array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/ditt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/one-click-demo-import/inc/Helpers.php on line 538

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

These Warnings are in One Click Demo Import plugins. This plugins is just recommended for you. Without it, you can import demos. Here is the directions: 1. Go to Admin panel > Tools > Import 2. Choose WordPress 3. Upload .xml file 4. Click “Upload file and import” 5. Check “Download and import file attachments” 6. Click “Summit” That’s it!

Note: above direction is just for importing .xml file. You need to import sliders manually.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/ditt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/one-click-demo-import/inc/OneClickDemoImport.php on line 207
```

suggests that ini_set() function should be enabled in the php configuration. You should ask your hosting provider to enable this function

If you still get warnings, you should contact the author of the theme